# Join and Multiply two DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to join two DataFrame by the common columns except for the last column, and multiply the last column by the values from two original tables?

**Example:**

Table X

```
   A  B  Value
0  1  1   1.0
1  1  0   0.5
2  0  1   0.5
3  0  0   0.0
```

Table Y

```
   B  C  Value
0  1  1   1.0
1  1  0   0.5
2  0  1   0.5
3  0  0   0.0
```

Expected Output:

```
   A  B  C  Value
0  1  1  1   1
1  1  1  0   0.5
2  1  0  1   0.25
3  1  0  0   0
4  0  1  1   0.5
5  0  1  0   0.25
6  0  0  1   0
7  0  0  0   0
```

Explain:

ex. (A=1, B=1, C=0) => 0.5, comes from

value 1 [(A=1, B=1) from X] multiply by value 0.5 [(B=1, C=0) from Y]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`merge`, calculate the new column, and drop the no longer needed columns.

```
# All common columns except last
cols = df1.columns[:-1].intersection(df2.columns[:-1]).tolist()

df = df1.merge(df2, on=cols)
df = df.assign(Value = df.Value_x*df.Value_y).drop(columns=['Value_x', 'Value_y'])
```

#### Output:

```
   A  B  C  Value
0  1  1  1   1.00
1  1  1  0   0.50
2  0  1  1   0.50
3  0  1  0   0.25
4  1  0  1   0.25
5  1  0  0   0.00
6  0  0  1   0.00
7  0  0  0   0.00
```